# C# Add extended interface to list

Tags: c#, interface

I'm currently trying to add a collection of interfaces to another collection - the problem is, i only want the extended interface, and not the parent.

Let me elaborate:

```
interface IScanner
{
    void scan();
}

interface IPhotocopier : IScanner
{
     void Copy();
}

public class PrintingBusiness
{
    List<IPhotocopier> Photocopiers { get; set; }
}

public class ScannerBusiness
{
    List<IScanner> Scanners { get; set; }
}

public class Program
{   
      static void Main(string[] args)
      {
            PrintingBusiness printerBusiness = new PrintingBusiness();
            printerBusiness.Photocopiers = new List<IPhotocopier>();
            printerBusiness.Photocopiers.Add(new HPPrinter());
            printerBusiness.Photocopiers.Add(new CanonPrinter())

            ScannerBusiness scannerBusiness = new ScannerBusiness();
            scannerBusiness.Scanners = new List<IScanner>();
            scannerBusiness.Scanners.Add(printerBusiness.Photocopiers); // Here i want to retreive all the IScanners from my Photocopiers collection, but i get an ArgumentError: Cannot Convert from List<IPhotocopier> to List<IScanner>. 

      }
}
```

I want to access the collection of IScanner interfaces from my Photocopiers collection - i thought i could do it directly by simply adding the Photocopiers collection to my Scanners collection - but to i need to iterate over each Photocopier and cast to IScanner and then add them to my Scanners collection? :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use the `AddRange` method, since that can iterate over the `Photocopiers` list and add all those items to the `Scanners` list:

```
scannerBusiness.Scanners.AddRange(printerBusiness.Photocopiers);
```

You won't need any conversion since the `IPhotocopier` instances can implicitly be casted to `IScanner`.

Also, don't forget to initialize your lists. They are `null` now.